# Reload another page when I click on button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a file `myfile.php`. In this file I have the following code:

```
<button type='submit' name='refresh' onclick='refresh()'></button>
<script>
    function refresh(){ 
        setTimeout(window.location.href = "summary.php",1000);
    }
</script>
```

When I click the refresh button my window's location is updated and the browser loads the file `summary.php`. However, I want to stay on `myfile.php` and refresh the file `summary.php` in a second tab.

Comment: Use `window.open("summary.php");`

Comment: how was it opened? window.open() ?

Comment: Use the second parameter of [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: summary.php is already open. I want to refresh this file on button press

Comment: window.open('summary.php'); take the control to summary.php, But I want to stay on my old file i.e. myfile.php

Comment: It sounds like you have two tabs/windows and want to trigger the second one to refresh from a button in the first one, is that correct? If so, the only way you can influence a second window is if it was opened by the first one via `window.open`.

Comment: @Herohtar You have approached my problem. But window.open does not meet my requirement as window.open everytime opens a new tab instead of refreshing the already opened tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first have to open the second tab using [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and save a reference to it so that you can access it later to reload when the button is clicked. This is the only way you can *directly* access/control a separate tab from JavaScript. Note that due to the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) you can only do this for pages that are on the same domain. If you're wanting to refresh a page on a different domain the best you can do is set `location.href` on the tab.

Here is a very simple example of how that might look using your code:

```
<button type="button" name="refresh" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
<script>
    let secondWindow = window.open('summary.php');
    function refresh() { 
        secondWindow.location.reload(true); // Use true to always force reload from the server
    }
</script>
```

This will cause `summary.php` to open in a new tab or window when you load `myfile.php`. After that, you should be able to click the refresh button in the first page and the second page will reload.

If you don't want `summary.php` to open automatically, you can add a manual way of opening the window:

```
<button type="button" name="open" onclick="open()">Open</button>
<button type="button" name="refresh" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
<script>
    let secondWindow;

    function open() {
      secondWindow = window.open('summary.php');
    }

    function refresh() {
      if (secondWindow) {
        secondWindow.location.reload(true); // Use true to always force reload from the server
      }
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to have to rely on JavaScript opening the second tab, you might look at the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) as an alternative option. You could send a "refresh" message from the first page when the button is clicked and have the second page refresh itself whenever it sees one of those messages.

Comment: @Imran If you update your question with an example of how you are using this code I can try to see what the problem is.

Comment: <button type='submit' name='refresh' onclick='refresh()'></button>
<script>
    function refresh(){ 
 var secondWindow=summary.php';
  secondWindow.location.reload(true);
}
</script>

Comment: @Imran You have to assign the variable outside of the refresh function. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: This code opens summary.php everytime when I press refresh button.

Comment: @Imran It does not if you are using the correct code. Please update your original question with the exact code you are using (not just part of it).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Your given code is working nicely, but I have a little problem when i refresh my page window.open opens the new tab. How to avoid auto tab opening on page refresh. I want to open the summary.php manually and when the summary.php is open refresh function updates the summary page

Comment: @Imran Unfortunately, you can't access the properties of a second tab like that unless you open it using `window.open`. If you just want the ability to open `summary.php` manually you could make a second function for the `window.open` and create a "Open" button that calls that function, then it wouldn't pop up automatically.

Comment: @Imran However, if you do want to be able to open `summary.php` completely manually (eg, by typing in the URL or something like that) another option you could use would be the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API). With that, you could have `summary.php` listen for messages and when the button is clicked on the first page, send a "refresh" message, which causes `summary.php` to reload itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(performance.navigation.type == 2){
 window.location.replace("www.google.com");
}

 </script>
```